# What is the way to send transactions extremely quickly?

Tags: solana-program

Does anyone know the best method for sending transactions that need to be confirmed extremely quickly? I'm currently using a paid RPC (from quicknode), it seems to be very fast for receiving signatures via websocket, but for sending transactions via HTTP it seems to be a bit slow (I don't know if it's due to caching or something). Does anyone have any suggestions for methods to send transactions that need to be sent and validated extremely quickly?

Comment: Hi disclosure that I work with QuickNode

Sending a transaction doesn't necessarily depend on a faster RPC but on various factors like the gas fee it's sent with, validator coverage or capacity, network traffic at the point, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of finding a faster RPC you can also try adding priority fees to the transaction in order for it to be prioritized in the blockchain and in turn  be validated quicker.

EDIT:
Yeah sure, using the solders python package you can use `priorityFee = set_compute_unit_price(amount in microlamports)` in order to create an **Instruction** that will add the priority fee.

Then assuming you already have an transaction you want to send and that this transaction uses a **compiled instruction**, you will basically have to create a new transaction by adding the two together. Lets assume this is your existing transaction
`raw_tx=VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(serialized_transaction))`, call it transaction **X** for sake of simplicity.

Next you want to store all the account keys of **X** into variable.

```
account_keys = raw_tx.message.account_keys
```

Also calculate the number of account keys, this will be handy later.

```
length_account_keys = len(account_keys)
```

And then you can append the account keys from the priorityFee instruction to the variable.

```
account_keys.append(priorityFee.program_id)
```

Next you would have append the instruction from **X** into a variable and create a new **compiled instruction** from the priority fee **instruction**. The program id index is the length of the account keys of **X** because it is being appended to the end of the account keys and the compiled instruction needs to know the index position of the account key in order to execute the priority fee instruction.

```
raw_instructions = raw_tx.message.instructions

new_instruction = CompiledInstruction(
    program_id_index=length_account_keys,
    data=priorityFee.data,
    accounts=raw_instructions[0].accounts,
)
```

Then you can add this **new_instruction** to the exisiting variable and create a new compiled instruction with both the priority fee and exisitng instructions from **X**.

```
raw_instructions.append(new_instruction)

new_tx = Message.new_with_compiled_instructions(
   num_required_signatures=raw_tx.message.header.num_required_signatures,
    num_readonly_signed_accounts=raw_tx.message.header.num_readonly_signed_accounts,
    num_readonly_unsigned_accounts=raw_tx.message.header.num_readonly_unsigned_accounts,
    account_keys=account_keys,
    recent_blockhash=raw_tx.message.recent_blockhash,
    instructions=raw_instructions,
)
```

And then youre ready to sign the **new_tx** and pass it to the blockchain. Hopefully this helps, if you have any question just ask.

Comment: You have any example how to do this using python?

Comment: I edited my original answer, hopefully its helpful, don't hesitate to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the complement! Your answer helped solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Send your transaction with skip_preflight. it'll give you the signature still which you can check later if it had been successful or not.

in node/react:

```
connection.sendTransaction(tx, [], {skipPreflight: true});
```

rust:

```
rpc_client
                    .send_transaction_with_config(
                        &tx,
                        solana_client::rpc_config::RpcSendTransactionConfig {
                            skip_preflight: true,
                            ..solana_client::rpc_config::RpcSendTransactionConfig::default()
                        },  
                    )
                    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers are great, and as a separate option, if you really want to spray transactions at the network, you can use the `TpuClient` in Rust, which sends transactions directly to the leader and a few other validators around.

Here's an example using it:

```
use {
    solana_client::{
        connection_cache::ConnectionCache,
        nonblocking::tpu_client::TpuClient,
        send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel::{
            send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel, SendAndConfirmConfig,
        },
        tpu_client::TpuClientConfig,
    },
    solana_rpc_client::nonblocking::rpc_client::RpcClient,
    solana_sdk::{
        commitment_config::CommitmentConfig, message::Message, signature::Signer,
        system_instruction,
    }
};

// some async function
async fn send_transactions() {
    let rpc_client = //
    let from = //
    let to = //
    let signer = //

    let blockhash = rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().await?;

    // make your transaction messages here
    let messages = (0..100)
        .map(|i| {
            Message::new_with_blockhash(
                &[system_instruction::transfer(&from, &to, i)],
                Some(&signer.pubkey()),
                &blockhash,
            )
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let now = Instant::now();
    let connection_cache = ConnectionCache::new_quic("connection_cache_cli_program_quic", 1);
    let rpc_client = Arc::new(rpc_client);
    let transaction_errors = if let ConnectionCache::Quic(cache) = connection_cache {
        let tpu_client = TpuClient::new_with_connection_cache(
            rpc_client.clone(),
            websocket_url,
            TpuClientConfig::default(),
            cache,
        )
        .await?;
        send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel(
            rpc_client,
            Some(tpu_client),
            &messages,
            &[signer],
            SendAndConfirmConfig {
                resign_txs_count: Some(5),
                with_spinner: true,
            },
        )
        .await
        .map_err(|err| format!("Data writes to account failed: {err}"))?
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

Important note: if you're using the `TpuClient` from an unstaked node, ie any client machine, you will be limited by the number of streams. For the most part, however, you can get a lot of transactions into the network quickly!